# Get JQuery data- that contains value with spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions: in the first one, I'm setting the `data-file_name` attribute using JQuery:

```
 "<input type=\"image\" + " data-file_name=" + result.fileName/>"
```

Which works great, but when I'm trying to retrieve that value from the second function if the `data-file_name value` contains spaces I just get the first word(for example if `data-file_name= "The book blue"` I just get `The`, if `data-file_name = "Red Dragon"` I just get on the second function `Red` it stops when it find an space...  )
This is the way I'm retrieving the value in the second function:

```
var fileName = $(this).data("file_name");
```

So `fileName variable` will not get the real value because it doesn't include anything behind the spaces, which way should I use to retrieve the value complete including spaces and everything?

Comment: try this : var fileName = $(this).attr("data-file_name");

Comment: There is a concatenation problem. Replace with this `"<input type=\"image\" data-file_name=\"" + result.fileName + "\" />"`

Comment: @Robiseb If you put it as an answer I will select it as the correct answer it works now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a concatenation problem.

Replace with this

```
"<input type=\"image\" data-file_name=\"" + result.fileName + "\" />"
```

Comment: Or better yet, with ES6 you can use template strings and  do the following:  `<input type="image" data-file_name="${result.fileName}" />`. A much cleaner approach, but depending on the user base and the application, ES6 might not be an option. Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1):

What you're creating isn't valid syntax.

```
// Invalid Syntax:
<input type="image" data-red dragon="" />
```

When you template or even produce this input via the server, the markup can't have a space on the data attribute.  Though it allows some customization.  The reason it fails with the space is because it is concating "Red" to your data attribute, but then treating "Dragon" as another attribute.

In essence, this is being created:

```
<input type="image" data-red="" dragon="" />
<input type="image" data-red="" />
```

Both aren't what you intended.  You would need to do remove the space, to correctly build that data attribute.  Your other option would be to place the filename as the value, rather than in the data attribute.  For instance:

```
<input type="image" data-filename="@FileName" />
```

Obviously, you would use whatever approach to generate where I placed `@FileName`.  Also you could use single quotes, then physically use double quotes to help simplify concatenation in JavaScript.